# Correct way of using field class in the Armadillo C++ library

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm trying to understand how I should correctly use the `field` class in the Armadillo C++ library, and I'm afraid the [Documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field) page is not totally clear to me. Say I want to create a `field` with 3 vectors with different number of elements. I guess I should initiate the `field` by

```
field<vec> res(3);
```

But if I want to initiate a `field` with 3 matrices of different dimensions (both different numbers of rows and columns), I should use:

```
field<mat> res(3, 1);
```

or

```
field<mat> res(3);
```

both seem to work...

Comment: can you clarify question?

Comment: Thanks for the response! The question is how the `field` class should be initiated when I want to store vectors and how when I want to store matrices?

Comment: I guess, you did not work with Matlab or it free analogues (Octave,Scilab) where scalar too matrix. Library Armadillo tries to provide a similar approach. So doesn't matter which of constructors you will use. All of this form apply to the field object, not to its content. That is the essence of template classes. Actually as written in the description - field is just a matrix/cube.